# How to execute a alert with XSS

Tags: php, html, xss

Hello I have to Execute a alert window with Cross Site Scripting but I dont know how.
I tried everything

This is the PHP CODE:

```
<?php
    $name="Exercise 4";
    $url="xss4.php";
    if (isset($_GET["q1"])) {
        $par1 = $_GET["q1"];    
    } else {
        $par1 = "";
    }
    if (isset($_GET["q2"])) {
        $par2 = $_GET["q2"];    
    } else {
        $par2 = "";
    }
    if (!(strripos($par1, "<") === false) and !(strripos($par1, ">") === false)) {
        $par1 = htmlentities($par1);
    }
    if (!(strripos($par2, "<") === false) and !(strripos($par2, ">") === false)) {
        $par2 = htmlentities($par2);
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title><?=$name?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="labs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main"><div id="content">
        <h1><?=$name?></h1>
        <form action="<?=$url?>" method="GET">
            <input name="q1" type="text" size="30"><br />
            <input name="q2" type="text" size="30"><br />
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
        <?php
            if ($par1) {
                echo "Some people say: $par1 <br/>";    
            }
            if ($par2) {
                echo "Others say: $par2";    
            }
        ?>
        </div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to create my alert window using the < > but I must have done it wrong because it didn't work, can someone please help me?
And Please explain it to me, because I realy dont know how I get to the solution

Comment: htmlentities will prevent your attempt, so you have to find a way to stop that from executing. Look closely at the `if` statements which precede the calls to htmlentities, and the function called within those statements

Comment: URL and name are defined as you have here or did you put static so the question wouldn't have undefined values?